# Swift - iOS 9: How do i present UIViewController with custom size in iOS 9?

Tags: ios, swift, presentviewcontroller

i have a view and i want to display a UIViewController with custom size. But i didn't succeed. Here is my code.

```
var vx = KeyboardViewController()
vx.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FormSheet
vx.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, 150)    
self.presentViewController(vx, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This UIViewController is displayed in the full screen size

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to give the presented view controller a custom `transitioningDelegate`, which will then be able to insert a custom UIPresentationController into the presentation process, whose `frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView` you will have overridden appropriately.

Comment: Working downloadable example project here: https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7

Comment: I don't understand the code, it's too complex for me. I've seen this answer, but didn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29219688/present-modal-view-controller-in-half-size-parent-controller . There is no more simple way to present half size uiviewcontroller?

Comment: That answer is exactly the same as what I'm telling you _and showing you_ how to do.