# How to present ViewController partially over another ViewController and still be able to interact with the bottom one?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I'm presenting a mostly transparent ViewController over another one right now, but it disables interaction with the ViewController underneath. Here is the code I am using as of now:

```
topController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
bottomController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.currentContext
bottomController.present(topController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

How do I partially present the top controller over the bottom controller while still allowing the bottom controller to be interacted with?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29219688/present-modal-view-controller-in-half-size-parent-controller   this will help you

Comment: adding and animating a uiview will also be helpful.

Comment: @MuhammedAzharudheen I've just done that, but I can't set the frame of the top UIViewController without disabling interaction with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to interact with `bottomController` you should add `UIViewController` as ChildViewController:

```
bottomController.addChildViewController(topController)
bottomController.view.addSubview(topController.view)
//set here frame or constraints for topController.view
```

If you want to dismiss `topController` you should call:

```
topController.removeFromParentViewController()
topController.view.removeFromSuperview()
```

For animations you can use:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration duration: TimeInterval, animations: @escaping () -> Void)
```

Comment: I've just done this, but I don't know how to set the frame of the top ViewController so that it doesn't disable the top one. When I set the top controller's frame to a CGRect, it succeeds in changing the frame, but ends up disabling the top controller.