# Connect programmatically created view to IB

Tags: swift, uipresentationcontroller

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45525284/11053269) answer, I managed to add half-modally presented `ViewControllerB` to `ViewControllerA`. However, in the example, `ViewControllerA` is just a red view. I would like to connect it to IB in order to customize it. I tried creating a view controller in IB of class `ViewControllerB` and connect one of its views to `@IBOutlet var menuView: UIView!` instead of creating `menuView` programmatically (as in the example). However, `nil` was found when adding `menuView` to the view as a subview. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of observations:

1. In that example, there is a line that says:

   ```
   let vc = ViewControllerB()
   ```

   You could define this view controller’s view in a NIB and this would work fine. But if you’re using storyboards, replace that with ...

   ```
   let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: “identifier")
   ```

   ... where `identifier` is some string that you supplied as the “Storyboard ID” in the “Identity inspector” in IB for that scene.
2. If this is being triggered by a button or something like that, you can also remove this `gotoVCB` in that sample, and just do the modal presentation right in IB like usual (e.g. <kbd>control</kbd>-dragging from the button to the next scene) and choosing “Present modally”. But you’d have to make sure that you configured all `init` methods, e.g.:

   ```
   class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {

       // used if you use NIBs or just call `init()`

       override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
           super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
           configure()
       }

       // used if you use storyboards

       required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
           super.init(coder: aDecoder)
           configure()
       }

       private func configure() {
           modalPresentationStyle = .custom
           transitioningDelegate = self
       }

       ...
   }
   ```
3. Unrelated to the immediate question, I might suggest splitting up [that answer’s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45525284/1271826) code into separate objects to prevent view controller “bloat”, with better separation of responsibilities between a transitioning delegate object, the animation controller, etc.

   For example, maybe:

   ```
   class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {

       let customTransitioningDelegate = PopUpMenuTransitioningDelegate()

       override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
           super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
           configure()
       }

       required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
           super.init(coder: aDecoder)
           configure()
       }

       func configure() {
           modalPresentationStyle = .custom
           transitioningDelegate = customTransitioningDelegate
       }

   }
   ```

   And

   ```
   class PopUpMenuTransitioningDelegate: NSObject, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
       func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
           return PopUpMenuAnimationController(transitionType: .presenting)
       }

       func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
           return PopUpMenuAnimationController(transitionType: .dismissing)
       }
   }
   ```

   And

   ```
   class PopUpMenuAnimationController: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
       enum TransitionType {
           case presenting
           case dismissing
       }

       let transitionType: TransitionType

       init(transitionType: TransitionType) {
           self.transitionType = transitionType
           super.init()
       }

       func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
           return 1
       }

       func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
           let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
           guard let toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to),
               let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from) else { return }

           switch transitionType {
           case .presenting:
               containerView.addSubview(toVC.view)

               var rect = fromVC.view.bounds
               let menuHeight = fromVC.view.bounds.height / 2
               rect.origin.y += fromVC.view.bounds.height
               rect.size.height = menuHeight
               toVC.view.frame = rect
               toVC.view.alpha = 0

               UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
                   rect.origin.y = menuHeight
                   toVC.view.frame = rect
                   toVC.view.alpha = 1
               }, completion: { _ in
                   transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
               })

           case .dismissing:
               UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
                   var rect = fromVC.view.frame
                   rect.origin.y = toVC.view.bounds.height
                   fromVC.view.frame = rect
                   fromVC.view.alpha = 0
               }, completion: { _ in
                   transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
               })
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   That decouples the transitioning delegate and animation controller from the view controller and lets you use this with other view controllers should you ever need to.

   Note, I’m also a little more careful about the parameter to `completeTransition`, too. Once you start playing around with interactive transitions, you might support cancelable transitions.