# Height of view as a modal popup - Swift

Tags: swift, view, popup, height, viewcontroller

In the app that I am creating with XCode I created a view that opens as a modal popup. I used this code:

```
@IBAction func open_view(_ sender: Any) {
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let VC_test_object = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC_Test")
    VC_test_object.modalPresentationStyle = .popover;
    self.present(VC_test_object, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

VC_Test is the ViewController in Storyboard. This is the result:

[image: View]

However, I would like to manage the height of the view to create a sort of menu.
As in this example screenshot (from the Documents app):

[image: Example]

I can't understand how to do it.

Could you tell me how to manage the height of the popup?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a code-your-self version this SO link and the answers below it is what you need: [Present modal view controller in half size parent controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29219688/present-modal-view-controller-in-half-size-parent-controller)

However, I would rather use this third party library : [Presentr](https://github.com/IcaliaLabs/Presentr)

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply.
I did some tests. The first answer doesn't work. The second covers the contents of the view created in interface builder. The third works well, but I had to make some changes.
I had to add a 50% black background in the main view and I had to enter a notification to remove the background when the second view is closed.
But in this way I cannot manage the tap on the background to close the second view.
I haven't solved 100%, but it's already something ...

Comment: Hey. As far as I understand, you should be able to use `PresentationType.bottomHalf` to do what you need and without the need of having 50% black background. You can see it the example in the Gif below: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/aca4ccf8f2b72cf20fa70d9c9b32eb88c5be304f/687474703a2f2f64616e69656c6f7a616e6f2e636f6d2f50726573656e74722f476966732f426f74746f6d48616c66536c6f772e676966

But since I dunno your exact use case, so not sure how relevant it is. Anyway good luck for the app !

Comment: Hi. I have not used Presentr. So I can't use PresentationType.bottomHalf. It doesn't matter, I still solved it in a strange way :) Thx for your help :)