# How to present (popover) view controller without previous view controller moving back (stop weird animation)

Tags: ios, swift

When you present (popover) a view controller the previous view controller kind of backs out of the screen. Is there any way to stop that from happenening.

Here is an example of what is happening: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIVjy.jpg

And here is an example of what I want to happen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nlrpr.jpg

The only code I'm using for presenting it

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "IdentifierName")
self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Do you only want to present your VC halfway up the screen like in your second gif, or do you still want to present it fullscreen like in the first gif?

Comment: I only want to present it half way.

Comment: Look like here is an answer for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29219688/present-modal-view-controller-in-half-size-parent-controller !

Answer (score 0):

If you want something like this:
[image]

First ViewController:

```
let sb = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Appointment", bundle: nil)
let popVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AppointConfirmationPopUpVC") as! AppointConfirmationPopUpVC
    
self.addChild(popVC)
popVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
self.view.addSubview(popVC.view)
popVC.didMove(toParent: self)
```

Second ViewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var bottomView: UIView!

viewdidLoad()
{
  self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.6)
  showAnimate()
}

func showAnimate(){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseIn],
                   animations: {
                    self.bottomView.center.y -= self.bottomView.bounds.height
                    self.bottomView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}

func hideAnimate()
{
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: [.curveLinear],
                   animations: {
                    self.bottomView.center.y += self.bottomView.bounds.height
                    self.bottomView.layoutIfNeeded()
                    self.view.center.y += self.view.bounds.height
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                    
    },  completion: {(_ completed: Bool) -> Void in
    })
}
```

Comment: This is a great first step, but how do I implement the interactive sliding gesture that the popover display has?